# IMACROS Error in code after converting iim code to javascript

Tags: javascript, syntax, imacros

have done this before but converting this part of IIM code to JAVSCRIPT, is giving me an error

IIM code (runs fine)

```
URL GOTO=abcDOTcom
EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#\\7 1RB7>DIV:type(1)" BUTTON=A
```

Converted to JAVSCRIPT Code

```
var macro;
macro =  "CODE:";
macro +=  "URL GOTO=abcDOTcom" + "\n"; 
macro +=  "EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR=\"#\\7 1RB7>DIV:type(1)\" BUTTON=A" + "\n"; 
iimPlay(macro)
```

i read that we have to comment out quotes with a \ before it. I did but still it isnt working

I feel the two \\ in the code before the 7 is an issue OR the SPACE after the 7 is an issue
How do i make sure sure it runs fine in JAVASCRIPT

Some syntax issue i am pretty sure
Thanks

Comment: I bet `\\7` needs to be `\\\\7`.

Comment: @Pointy do you mean i need to Type like following in JS
......SELECTOR=\"#\\\\7 1RB7>......

Comment: @Pointy just edited the question a bit..have a look

Comment: Yes, exactly. You need two `\` characters  to make it into the string, because (presumably; I'm not familiar with imacros) it will re-parse the string. So you start off with `\\\\`, and JavaScript will make a string with `\\` in it, so that imacros will end up seeing `\7`.  Again, I'm completely guessing here.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you used iMacros Code creator, which is outdated since 2013 (If I'm not wrong)
Keep in mind when using Java Script and Strings to [escape several characters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

You can also use an [imacros java script converter](https://xs-sol.com/imacros-java-script-converter/) which does the thing too.

Answer (score 0):

```
var macro;
macro =  "CODE:";
macro +=  "URL GOTO=abcDOTcom" + "\n"; 
macro +=  'EVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR="#\\7 1RB7>DIV:type(1)" BUTTON=A' + "\n"; 
iimPlay(macro)
```

With EVENT you have to use ' instead of " . And remove \ in front of ".

The code above works.

Comment: thanks for reply. I tried the ' thing but its giving me same error (SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified, line 1 (Error code: -1001) ) 
but the adding \ in front of " and adding \\ before \\7 works fine . Are you sure about this?

Comment: If it works for you then suggest correction and I will edit my answer.